# SAP BusinessObjects - Merging dimensions with no directly related attributes

Tags: business-objects

Given the following 3 queries

Query 1

```
SELECT
  COMPONENTINFO__SOFTWARE.SOFTWARENAME,
  COMPONENTINFO__SOFTWARE.SOFTWAREVERSION,
  COMPONENTINFO__SOFTWARE.PARENTOID,
  COMPONENTINFO__SOFTWARE.OID,
  COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO.OID,
  COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO.HWSERIAL,
  COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO.COMPONENTID
FROM
  COMPONENTINFO__SOFTWARE,
  COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO
WHERE
  ( COMPONENTINFO__SOFTWARE.PARENTOID=COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO.OID  )
```

Query 2

```
SELECT
  V_MACH.OID,
  V_MACH.NAME,
  V_MACH.IPADDR
FROM
  V_MACH
```

Query 3

```
SELECT
  V_VERSIONINFO.MACHINEOID,
  VM_VERSIONINFO_VERSIONINFOINFO.HWSERIAL,
  VM_VERSIONINFO_VERSIONINFOINFO.OSVERSION,
  VM_VERSIONINFO_VERSIONINFOINFO.PARENTOID,
  VM_VERSIONINFO_VERSIONINFOINFO.OID,
  COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO.PARENTOID,
  V_VERSIONINFO.OID
FROM
  V_VERSIONINFO,
  VM_VERSIONINFO_VERSIONINFOINFO,
  COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO
WHERE
  ( VM_VERSIONINFO_VERSIONINFOINFO.PARENTOID=V_VERSIONINFO.OID  )
```

I'm trying to produce a report (Webi, using the rich client) that shows in 1 table:

V_MACH.NAME, COMPONENTINFO__SOFTWARE.SOFTWARENAME, COMPONENTINFO__SOFTWARE.SOFTWAREVERSION

But no matter what dimensions I merge, it won't let me put the NAME field alongside the software version fields.

I've tried to merge on:
VM_VERSIONINFO_VERSIONINFOINFO.HWSERIAL + COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO.HWSERIAL.
VM_VERSIONINFO_VERSIONINFOINFO.OID + COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO.OID (I found these represent the same values for each machine)

But nothing works.

Is the only way to do a join at the SQL level? I was hoping to avoid that but if it's the only way then that's ok.

Comment: So what's the common field between Query 1 and Query 2?

Comment: None. The links between them are:
Query 2.V_MACH.OID -> Query 3.V_VERSIONINFO.MACHINEOID
Then
Query 3.VM_VERSIONINFO_VERSIONINFOINFO.OID ->COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO.OID

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you need to do is this:

1. 1) Create a merged dimension between V_MACH.OID in Query 2 and
   V_VERSIONINFO.MACHINEOID in Query 3. Call the merged dim
   "machineoid".
2. Create a merged dimension between
   VM_VERSIONINFO_VERSIONINFOINFO.OID in Query 3 and
   COMPONENT_VERSION_INFO.OID in Query 1.  Call the merged dim "oid".
3. Create a new variable as a **detail** type, defined as
   `=[V_MACH.NAME]`, and its associated dimension as the merged
   `machineoid` dimension. Call it `name_detail`.
4. Use the two merged dims in place of the
   underlying dims in your report block, then add in the `name_detail` variable.

The reason you're having trouble is that BO can't recognize what Query 2.NAME should be associated with.  By creating a detail variable, you are explicitly telling it that it is an attribute of the now-merged OID dimension.